# What is difference between plpython, plpythonu, plpython2u

Tags: postgresql, plpython

what is difference between plpython, plpythonu, plpython2u.

What does u and 2u mean.

Looking around I could't find any info on that matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PL/Python procedural language allows PostgreSQL functions to be written in the Python language.
PL/Python2U untrusted procedural language

Comment: 2 means version I assume? (python2)

Comment: what does plpythonu means? 2 or 3?

Comment: @1.618 according to the official postgresql docs: "The language named plpythonu implements PL/Python based on the default Python language variant, which is currently Python 2. (This default is independent of what any local Python installations might consider to be their “default”, for example, what /usr/bin/python might be.) The default will probably be changed to Python 3 in a distant future release of PostgreSQL, depending on the progress of the migration to Python 3 in the Python community."